# Can't select objects in wireframe and can't see the wireframe

Tags: wireframe, select

Today I downloaded blender 2.91 and started working on a scene when suddenly, I switch to wireframe mode and I can't select objects, and also I can't even see the wireframes just outlines of the objects. It's frustrating and I can't find anyone with the same problem. By the way, I even opened the old files from blender 2.7 and 2.8 (in 2.91) and I still have the problem
It's probably a rly dumb question but help would be appreciated.
Here's how it looks

[image]

and this one is a random pic from google images but just to show you what i want
[image]

Comment: It looks like you have x-ray enabled. Click the button that looks like 2 offset squares to the left of the "viewport preview" circle buttons at the top right of the 3D viewport. If that doesn't fix it, it could be an AMD GPU issue, but it's hard to tell. Have you updated your drivers recently? (newest ones cause problems)

Comment: I did update the drivers 3 days ago and haven't used blender since then, I can't find the solution anywhere so I suppose it could be that

Comment: Its been a VERY common problem recently. Rolling back to an older version should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, cheers

Comment: Have the same issue with an AMD GPU were you able to fix it?